# HTML 5 audio.playbackRate not working in iPad but works on Safari on Windows

Tags: ipad, html, html5-audio

Following code does not have any effect (audio continues to play in the same manner before pressing the PlayFast button iPad. It works beautifully on Safari on windows box

```
function playFast() 

       { 
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]; 
            myVideo.playbackRate = myVideo.playbackRate + 1; 
            alert(myVideo.playbackRate);
       }
```

Initially the `playbackRate` is set to 1

Can any one please help.

Comment: This isn't the first issue I've seen people come across with HTML5 audio problems on the iPad. I need to get myself one of those so I can start figuring them out. Wish I could help.

Comment: @kinakuta : I too am facing same problem with playbackrate in my html5 video :( any solution anyone

Answer (score 3):

To give an updated answer with the official [statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) from Apple on iOS:

> You can set the audio or video playbackRate property to nonzero values to play media in slow motion (values >0 and <1) or fast forward (values >1) in Safari on the desktop. **Setting playbackRate is not currently supported on iOS.**

Having said that I have managed to change the playbackRate on iPad/iOS7 with the following code. It seems you need to pause the video before the playbackRate can be set. I am just wondering now if the Apple document is up to date (?)

```
<video controls id="videoTag" width="640" height="360" preload="none">
<source src="media/360p.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' id="mp4Source">
</video>
<div id="change">change rate to x2</div>
<div id="change2">change rate to x0.5</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var video = document.getElementById('videoTag');
video.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.pause();
    video.playbackRate = 2.0;
    video.play();
},false);
document.getElementById('change2').addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.pause();
    video.playbackRate = 0.5;
    video.play();
},false);
},false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can set the audio or video playbackRate property to nonzero values
>   to play media in slow motion (values >0 and <1) or fast forward
>   (values >1) in Safari on the desktop and iOS 6+.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-DontLinkElementID_1

Answer (score 1):

Playback Rate in JavaScript

You can set the audio or video playbackRate property to nonzero values to play media in slow motion (values >0 and <1) or fast forward (values >1) in Safari on the desktop. **Setting playbackRate is not currently supported on iOS.**