# adding custom controls for seeking to the controlbar

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I have a use case where I need to seek forward and backwards in the video using custom buttons.   I've attached a screenshot of my player (linked below), including controls at the bottom for (-10 -5 +5 +10).  It works so when clicked, the video seeks to the correct position.

Picture of my player: http://tinyurl.com/k93xnya

I cannot, after hours of research, figure out how to do the same on the controlbar?   I need them to be controlbar options so they can be used in fullscreen mode.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using videojs. Adding custom buttons to videojs control bar can be tricky. You can find articles on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550897/videojs-4-0-plugin-how-to-properly-add-items-to-the-controlbar/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524879/videojs-add-only-play-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984161/adding-custom-video-js-control-bar-buttons). You probably need to develop your own [plugin](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/plugins.md) for better results.

You could also consider building your own set of [controls](http://dev.opera.com/articles/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/) for your HTML5 media player. More on going full screen with HTML5 media element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

Comment: I took your advice and created a new plugin very similar to the video-speed plugin and its working great. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Florestan06, any idea why plugins won't show on an iPad?   Its showing the custom controls (not native), but its not showing the speed plugin or the new one I just created.

Comment: Videojs support on iPad has been known to be partial. I have been using my own HTML5 player for a while because of such things. Also take into account that some features like playbackRate are not fully supported in iOS. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436232/html-5-audio-playbackrate-not-working-in-ipad-but-works-on-safari-on-windows

Comment: In my recent testing using a different player, playbackRate was working fine on the iPad.  But since switching to videojs, I cannot even get those controls to show up, so I can't test it.

Comment: Video.js skins are disabled on mobile by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697473/videojs-4-native-controls-now-default-on-mobile

Answer (score 1):

For one of my plugins I use this approach to insert a "previous" and "next" button on each side of the play/pause toggle.

-First we create/add the new controls to the control bar with `addChild()`

-I then use a function to find the location of the play button since that is my reference point

-Once I know the location of the play button I can insert the "previous" button before it

-Once I know the new location of the play button I can insert the "next" button after (before the next sibling) it.

```js
this.playlist.advancePlaylistButton = this.controlBar.addChild('advancePlaylist');
this.playlist.regressPlaylistButton = this.controlBar.addChild('regressPlaylist');

var playToggleLocation = 0;

var playLocation = function() {
    var controlBarChildren = this.controlBar.el().childNodes;
    var loc = -1;
    for ( var x = 0; x < controlBarChildren.length; x++ ) {
        if ( controlBarChildren[x].className.indexOf('vjs-play-control') != -1) {
            loc = x;
            break;
        }
    }
    return loc;
};


playToggleLocation = playLocation();
this.controlBar.el().insertBefore( this.playlist.regressPlaylistButton.el(), this.controlBar.el().childNodes[playToggleLocation] );

this.controlBar.el().insertBefore( this.playlist.advancePlaylistButton.el(), this.controlBar.el().childNodes[playToggleLocation+1] );
```